# rxjs - Iterate back in Observables

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, angular2-observables, rxjs-lettable-operators

Every time a new value is produced I need to compare it with all previous values and only if a condition is met it will be added to the stream.

How can this be done with observables?

Comment: Which type of comparison do you need to perform? For instance, if you want to check whether the value is a new value, never emitted before, than you can use the operator `distinct`. If you give more details maybe we can help you more.

Comment: distinct does not apply. The values are strings and the comparison function is similarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example, maybe a little convoluted, which should do something similar to what you are looking for

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

const values = ['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'db', 'bc', 'cc', 'cb', 'cc']

Observable.from(values)
// accumulate all previous values into an array of strings
.scan((previousValues, thisValue) => {
    previousValues.push(thisValue)
    return previousValues
}, [])
// create an object with the previous objects and the last one
.map(previousValues => {
    const lastValue = previousValues[previousValues.length - 1]
    return {previousValues, lastValue}
})
// filters the ones to emit based on some similarity logic
.filter(data => isNotSimilar(data.lastValue, data.previousValues))
// creates a new stream of events emitting only the values which passed the filter
.mergeMap(data => Observable.of(data.lastValue))
.subscribe(
    value => console.log(value)
)

function isNotSimilar(value: string, otherValues: Array<string>) {
    const otherValuesButNotLast = otherValues.slice(0, otherValues.length - 1);
    const aSimilar = otherValuesButNotLast.find(otherValue => otherValue[0] === value[0]);
    return aSimilar === undefined;
}
```